# ambiguous reference to System.Data.Services.Client and Microsoft.Data.Services.Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've been trying to port a web reference to OData Exigo API from a website to web application. Getting this error whenever I try to run the web application which uses this reference. I do not have a reference to the system.data.services.client anywhere in the project. Tried to uninstall from GAC but got an error because it is part of the .NET framework. What can I do?

Parser Error Message: Reference.datasvcmap: The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\myapp\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try specifying the assembly explicitly in the type name?

Comment: no, I've been looking for examples of that, not sure how to do that

Comment: There will be something like DataServiceCollection<T>([query]); Change it to specify the whole path Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection<T>([query]);

Comment: thanks guys, got me thinking the right way.. I had an old excluded folder in the project called app web references, which even though it was excluded, was impacting the project for some reason. removed it and moved on with this. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Remove reference to System.Data.Services.Client if exists

Answer (score 0):

This can be only done by 
`using Client = System.Data.Services.Client
using Client = Microsoft.Data.Services.Client` 
where which Client reference is required.